# vscode module doesn't work from simple script

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

So I have no problem using the vscode node module from the yeoman generated vs code extension.

But is there a reason why the module doesn't seem to work from just a fresh simple script to use for testing?

I get no intellisense errors in code and my vscode.d.ts file is where it should be.

index.ts:

```
import * as vscode from "vscode";
console.log(vscode);
```

index.js:

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var vscode = require("vscode");
console.log(vscode);
```

package.json:

```
{
"name": "vscodetemp",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "postinstall": "node ./node_modules/vscode/bin/install"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.13.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "vscode": "^1.0.0"
}
}
```

Exception:

```
module.js:471
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'vscode'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\temp\vscodeTemp\index.js:3:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-vscode/issues/68#issuecomment-311860868

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this will not work as the vscode "node_module" implementation is only accessible from within the vscode runtime. More info here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6586.